# pypyodbc: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send())

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc, pypyodbc

My python script reads through around half of the dataset (around 5000 rows out of 10000) and all of a sudden produces this error midway:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send())

I'm using pypyodbc to connect to the Azure SQL server. I haven't been able to find the solution anywhere online. I don't even know whats the cause that's leading to this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are doing well. Have you had a chance to look at [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) and [pymssql](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-windows/)?

They have a better community presence and are actively maintained. If the script fails with these drivers as well, there might be an issue with your script. I can try to help you troubleshoot if you share it.

Let me know if the issue gets fixed with the other drivers and if it does not I can help you out.

Thanks,

Meet Bhagdev

Program Manager, Microsoft

Comment: I had trouble with PyPyODBC for accessing SQL Azure - wouldn't allow me to switch database from 'master' - I switched my code to using PyODBC based on comments here and it works.  Here's what my working code looks like:

```conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
                                  server='"tcp:xxxx-db.database.windows.net,1433',
                                  database='SomeDB',
                                  uid='readOnly@xxxx-db', pwd='xxyyzz')```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed. And I observed that the package last updated in 2013. It's an old and no longer maintenance package for Python ODBC. So I don't recommend to continue to use it to access the latest Azure SQL Database.

I strongly recommended you to use the package `pymssql`. It's the Azure offical recommend odbc driver for Python, please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-libraries/.

It can very good support any OS environment  contains Windows, Linux, MacOS. You can refer to these docs https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-windows/, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-ubuntu-linux/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-mac-osx/ to getting started.

If you want to dive into the package usgae, please refer to the offical document http://pymssql.org/en/latest/index.html.

Best Regards.