# Python flask azure connection and driver needed azure driver needed

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, pypyodbc

How do I find the `SQL azure` driver for my `pypyodbc` application.

[gte 2.0] -->
Content relevant to Named Framework versions 2.0 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

There was an existing SO thread [pypyodbc: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981390/pypyodbc-microsoftodbc-sql-server-driverdbnetlibconnectionwrite-send/33362209), which got some issue when using `pypyodbc`. Based on your short & unclear description, I don't know why you want to use it to connect SQL Azure, and whether you will also get the similar issue. So I suggest you can consider for using Azure offical recommended Python driver `pyodbc` or `pymssql`, please see the document for them to knwo how to install & use these driver.